# Error when copying ssh keys from another computer

Tags: git, ssh

I copied my ssh keys from one computer to another to grant access to all servers without update them all.

I simply copied over the `id_rsa` and the `id_rsa.pub` files into the `~/.ssh` directory.

I then tried to use Git and got this issue:

```
$ git pull 
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I just needed to run:

```
$ ssh-add
```

And, the git commands worked perfectly.